# Printing a colored string in TASM/assembly as it is, eg, 13 as carriage return, not garbage values

Tags: string, assembly, colors, x86, tasm

Good day! I'm new in assembly language and I'm trying to print a simple "Hello World" with colors in it. It works but when I now add, for example, `13, 10`, it does not display carriage return line feed but displays other characters (musical note and a circle). Here is my code:

```
.MODEL SMALL
.DATA
.stack

hello db 13,10,'Hello World'
      db 13,10,'    #####     ',0        ; there are spaces
ROW1 DB 12
COL DB 20

.CODE
.STARTUP
MOV AL, 3       ; 80x25 color
INT 10H         ; video BIOS call   
MOV AH, 2       ; set cursor position
MOV BH, 0       ; display page number
 mov bl,2
MOV DH, ROW1        ; row number
MOV DL, COL     ; column number
INT 10H         ; video BIOS call
CALL FAR PTR DISP   ; display first line of video text

.EXIT

DISP PROC FAR
        MOV SI, 0   ; set up array pointer
NEXT:   MOV AL, hello[SI]; get name character
    CMP AL, 0   ; exit if character is 0
    JZ EXIT     
    MOV BH, 0   ; display page number
    MOV BL, [BP+SI] ; get attribute
    MOV CX, 1   ; do 1 character
    MOV AH, 9   ; write character/attribute on screen
    INT 10H     ; video BIOS call
    INC SI      ; point to next character/attribute
    ADD DL, 1   ; move two columns to the right
    MOV AH, 2   ; set cursor position
    INT 10H     ; video BIOS call
    JMP NEXT    ; and continue
EXIT:   RET
DISP ENDP

END
```

Please help me fix the code so that what is **written in the `hello` variable be seen in the console**. Also, how can I **get rid of the blinking colors**? I just got a list of colors in the internet but when I typed it here, it blinks (`mov bl, 2` as green but it blinks).

Answer (score 0):

As I responded to you to your another question, from [Ralf Brown's Interrupt List](http://www.ctyme.com/rbrown.htm):

```
INT 10 - VIDEO - WRITE CHARACTER AND ATTRIBUTE AT CURSOR POSITION
    AH = 09h
    AL = character to display
    BH = page number (00h to number of pages - 1) (see #00010)
        background color in 256-color graphics modes (ET4000)
    BL = attribute (text mode) or color (graphics mode)
        if bit 7 set in <256-color graphics mode, character is XOR'ed
          onto screen
    CX = number of times to write character
Return: nothing
Notes:  all characters are displayed, including CR, LF, and BS
    replication count in CX may produce an unpredictable result in graphics
      modes if it is greater than the number of positions remaining in the
      current row
    With PhysTechSoft's PTS ROM-DOS the BH, BL, and CX values are ignored
      on entry.
```

As it says: **Notes:  all characters are displayed, including CR, LF, and BS**.

You have to interpret carrier return (CR, `0x0d`) yourself. So if the input is `0x0d` (`13` in decimal) do as explained below, otherwise if the input is something else, handle it as you currently do.

So, for CR, read the current cursor location and then change the cursor location with the following `int 10h` calls:

First, get the current cursor position:

```
INT 10 - VIDEO - GET CURSOR POSITION AND SIZE
    AH = 03h
    BH = page number
        0-3 in modes 2&3
        0-7 in modes 0&1
        0 in graphics modes
Return: AX = 0000h (Phoenix BIOS)
    CH = start scan line
    CL = end scan line
    DH = row (00h is top)
    DL = column (00h is left)
Notes:  a separate cursor is maintained for each of up to 8 display pages
    many ROM BIOSes incorrectly return the default size for a color display
      (start 06h, end 07h) when a monochrome display is attached
    With PhysTechSoft's PTS ROM-DOS the BH value is ignored on entry.
```

In the output, `dh` is the current row. So do `inc dh` and then set the rest of parameters for:

```
INT 10 - VIDEO - SET CURSOR POSITION
    AH = 02h
    BH = page number
        0-3 in modes 2&3
        0-7 in modes 0&1
        0 in graphics modes
    DH = row (00h is top)
    DL = column (00h is left)
```

However, you don't say in your question what you want to do when you are on the bottom row and there is CR in the input. You should check that situation too and handle it the way you prefer.

And then:

```
inc si
jmp next
```

Comment: Thanks again, sir! I'll work on this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [function 0Eh](http://www.ctyme.com/intr/rb-0106.htm) for `CR` and `LF`. It will advance the cursor position:

> VIDEO - TELETYPE OUTPUT
>
> AH = 0Eh
>   AL = character to write
>   BH = page number
>   BL = foreground color (graphics modes only)
>
> Desc: Display a character on the screen, advancing the cursor and scrolling the screen as necessary
>
> **Notes: Characters 07h (BEL), 08h (BS), 0Ah (LF), and 0Dh (CR) are interpreted and do the expected things**.